# Install File Using POM instead of commandline

Tags: maven

I'm currently using:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={path/to/my/legacy.jar} -DgroupId=horrible -DartifactId=legacy.jar -Dversion=1.2.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

to import some old legacy jars into my repo. This has worked fine and is the recommended approach. It seems as though this could be done with a POM instead of at the commandline + script that I'm using now. I think it's cleaner to have:

```
mvn install:install-file
```

and let my repo store the version details rather than store this information in a non-maven script (which is odd for maven). I tried to expose these -D settings via the settings tag but that didn't work. Has any one else tried this and got it to work?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but why do you have to script it? Surely you only need to import these legacy jars into your repo once?

Comment: Just a maintenance thing, this is so if we need to export to the repo again (for whatever reason) we export with the same groupId/version number.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Okay, answering my own question :P. You can do this by defining properties, I originally assumed the groupId etc were auto exported as properties but they are not.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.whatever</groupId>
  <artifactId>Stuff</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>

  <description>
  Description of why this horrible jar exists.
  </description>

  <properties> 
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <packaging>${project.packaging}</packaging>
    <file>mylegacy.jar</file>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

You can now install files using:

```
mvn install
```

and this pom.xml. I have tested this with maven 3 and not 2.

For multiple files also see [Maven POM file for installing multiple 3rd party commercial libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237022/maven-pom-file-for-installing-multiple-3rd-party-commercial-libraries)

Comment: I also found this, which may work better if you have multiple jars: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802280/multiple-installinstall-file-in-a-single-pom-xml

Comment: Helpful to know that exporting the properties is necessary. That was my hangup.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237022/maven-pom-file-for-installing-multiple-3rd-party-commercial-libraries

Comment: can i install and use dependency in same pom?

Comment: This does almost what I want. But it also generates and installs a default JAR, which I would rather avoid.

Comment: thanks for the Maven method, but not sure I see the benefit of a 30+ lines pom vs 1 line cli command :-/