# I Got Trouble While Importing Dependencies in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am developing a Maven project on IntelliJ Idea. I want to say that these things that I mentioned below is worked on Windows, now I am trying this on Ubuntu. I tried to add dependencies with following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/..pat_here..cytoscapeswing-3.5.1.jar -DgroupId=cytoscapeswing -DartifactId=cytoscapeswing -Dversion=3.5.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And I got "BUILD SUCCESS" message. Then I added this dependency to my project like this:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>cytoscapeswing</groupId>
        <artifactId>cytoscapeswing</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

But when trying to build the project, IntelliJ does not see the library that I added. I mean there were no "cytoscapeswing" library in external library tab. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked in your local repository that your dependency is properly added? Are you sure your IntelliJ's Maven repository points to the same repository than the one used for your `mvn` command?

Comment: Can you build the project from command line with the mvn command instead of from intellij?

Comment: @DamCx Yes I am sure it points same repository. How can I check local repository? The library that I added does not exist in the list that libraries are listed.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov I could not find the way to do that, can you write the whole command? I will try.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/

Comment: @Synch Yes, it is exist in ~/.m2/repository direction

Comment: @JollyRoger In IntelliJ, do File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build tools > Maven, and there, you'll be able to find the path used for your local repository within Eclipse. Then open the path in your file browser and check if your dependency can be found there or not

Comment: @DamCx The path was different from '~/.m2/repository'. But the dependency file is exist here as well. '/home/erkan/.m2/repository'

Comment: @JollyRoger `~` is shell shorthand for your home directory.

Comment: '~/.m2/repository' and '/home/erkan/.m2/repository' are two different wayes to write the same path on a linux OS. Then, I can't really explain the difference you are having, then, with the few info we have here

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No it is not. Okey I see that '~/.m2/repository' and '/home/erkan/.m2/repository' is same. I am just new at ubuntu.

Comment: @DamCx I just noticed that '~/.m2/repository' and '/home/erkan/.m2/repository' is same, sorry I am new at ubuntu. What information do you need?

Comment: In your maven config file, is your local repository configured as a mirror to use?

Comment: First make sure you can actually build the project by Maven from command line. This will help to understand if the issue is IDE configuration or the Maven one. In the project directory with your main pom.xml execute `mvn compile`. You may need to add Maven executable (`mvn`) to the PATH environment variable to be able to execute `mvn` command, see https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Answer (score 0):

Add your dependency in your `pom.xml`. Then, in IntelliJ while inside `pom.xml`, right click -> "Maven" -> "Reimport" and let IntelliJ import it for you.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain (consider copy pasting values) that the values you used with install-file is the exact same as you have in your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

First, check the local repository, and make sure the lib is imported successfully.

Then, check the IntelliJ Idea setting, make sure the value of `Settings`->`Build, Exexution, Deployment`->`Build Tools`->`Maven`->`Local repository` is the correct path, if not, check the `Override` box, and overwrite the path.

Comment: I have already tried this as well. The path was different but the library that I wanted to add is exist in here as well. Also I change the path to the local repository '~/.m2/repository', but it did not worked again. You can see the same solution recommended by DamCx in the comments of my post that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you executed the `mvn install..` command after IntelliJ scanned the local repository it may not have been indexed correctly.  This is rare but not unheard of.

Try

```
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart
```

to see if it helps on the situation

Comment: No, unfortunately it did not help. I thought about it before actually but I did not know rescan in this way. So I just restarted IntelliJ, both way did not helped.

Comment: In that case, you may have made a typo in the installation procedure.  Consider looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802280/multiple-installinstall-file-in-a-single-pom-xml