# Maven - How to extract a dependency inside another ZIP dependency?

Tags: maven, zip, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a `maven` project.

Inside that project, I have a **.zip** dependency that carries a *jar* and I need to extract that *jar* out of the *zip* dependency and have maven use the *jar* as a dependency. I can currently download and unpack the zip but, cannot figure out a way to add the unpacked *jar* as a dependency for the project during the build process.

Here is what I'm currently doing for unpacking:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>${foo.version}</version>
  <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <configuration>
          <includeGroupIds>com.bar</includeGroupIds>
          <includeArtifactIds>foo</includeArtifactIds>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
          <type>jar</type>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

I read up on some other posts that you could try adding the jar to the class path using this.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <additionalClasspathElements>
           <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/target</additionalClasspathElement>
   </additionalClasspathElements>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Even doing so I was still unable to reference the packages in **foo.jar** in my project.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: This is a little strange... Why are you downloading a zip that contains your dependency? Can't you just put the dependency inside the dependencies list?

Comment: In the zip file there is a .dll file that is needed by the jar in order to run. I agree that it would be nice to just add the jar as a dependency in the dependency list.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I've faced the same problem. I had a *zip* file as my dependency, and during the build process I need to extract it and separate the content inside my generated package.

I don't know what are you using to deliver your project, but at that time I've used the `maven-antrun-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</plugin>
```

With this, I've used the tag `unzip` inside my `target` configuration. As you can see [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) or [here](https://www.coderanch.com/t/474329/build-tools/unzip-file-maven-plugin). I just don't recommend you to use the `task` tag as they're using, you'd better prefer the `target` tag.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For maven to use it without subtly breaking stuff elsewhere, you must install the jar into your local repository.

I would suppose that a combination of unpacking the zip file in target/ and then invoking install:install-file on the resulting jar could do what you need.  I asked some years back how to integrate *that* in a normal build - you might find the answer relevant. [Multiple install:install-file in a single pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10802280/53897)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that, after unpacking the zip, you have foo.jar in your module's target folder: `${project.build.directory}/foo.jar`

Having this in place, you can then declare a [System Dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) pointing to that jar, e.g.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo.jar</artifactId>
  <systemPath>${project.build.directory}/foo.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Tip: if you dont want to delete/re-download the jar each time you do a clean (some IDE will complain the the jar is not always present) just download it once in the `${project.basedir}`.

To download the jar once, you can put your "unpack" execution in a [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) that gets activated only when the jar is missing.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <file>
        <missing>${project.basedir}/foo.jar</missing>
      </file>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```