# Maven: How to add all jar files in lib folder during a web application build

Tags: java, maven

I have an old project. I am trying to add maven build to the project.
All the jar files in the project are present currently in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Is there a way to add these jar files to the classpath during source compilation and then have it in the war file lib

Comment: Create a fat-jar, enable the option of including all the dependencies in the jar file. See, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including all the jars in a directory within the Java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath)

Comment: @KumarAnkit Will this handle signed jars properly?

Comment: What do you mean _properly_?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the places where switching to Maven hurts.  There are a lot of suggestions where most short-circuit something you will need later, and hurt you there.  I would suggest that you

- Move your jar files out of the lib folder into another project folder not meaning anything special to Maven.
- For all jars that you easily recognize, make the proper Maven dependency in your pom file.  This will allow Maven to download sources and javadoc if present.
- For the remaining jars, you can tell Maven to install them as part of your normal build as custom dependencies.  I asked the same question years back and got a very useful response at [Multiple install:install-file in a single pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10802280/53897).  This will allow you to get up and running quickly.
- When you have the time, locate proper replacements for your custom dependencies.

Take your time doing this.  It is tedious work but it pays off quickly.

Comment: I have a lot of jar files very old ones. I think I better stick with Ant. It would be good, if maven can support this in future

Comment: Ant has disadvantages but if you have something that works then good for you. Maven  will most likely never support this.