# 3rd party dependency libs in project local folder

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, maven-3

There are a few 3rd party dependency libraries my project need to use, they are not in the maven repository. I put them into a folder called `3rd_deps` in project folder, and in `pom.xml`, I have following section to add the local folder:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>3rd-deps</id>
    <url>file:///project_workspace/3rd_deps<url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

But when I use `install-plugin:install-file` to install the dependency libs, I found it copy files into `$HOME/.m2` folder, not project local folder, this would be wrong because the libs needs to be committed to git server so that everyone can build the project. How can I make the 3rd libs proper installed so that they can stay in project folder and recognized by `maven`.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802280/multiple-installinstall-file-in-a-single-pom-xml

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are going about this the wrong way.  The dependencies should not end up in your source code repository.  That is not where 3rd-party dependencies belong.

I can think of three alternatives that are (IMO) better.

The first approach is to find out if the folks who created and maintain the dependencies have publish them in *any* Maven compatible repository.  If they have, then you can use your Maven settings file to tell Maven to fetch artifacts directly from their repository.  For more details, please refer to https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories.   Alternatively, you can specify the repositories in your project's POM file; see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html.

The second approach is to set up an organizational repository and upload the 3rd party artifacts there.  Then use the Maven settings (as above) to use your organizational repository.  You *could* even publish the 3rd-party artifacts to downstream organizations via your organizational repository, though that is dubious from a software engineering / business practice perspective.

The third approach is to write a script that fetches the dependencies from their canonical locations and then uses `mvn install-plugin:install-file` to add them to the developer's local Maven repo.  Include that script in your project's source repo and explain how to use it in the project README file ... or whatever.