# Maven POM file for installing multiple 3rd party commercial libraries

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have a bunch of projects which are dependant on a set of commercial 3rd party libraries. We currently don't have a company repository so I have to install the libraries in my own local repo.

Running `mvn install:installFile -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=<file> -DgroupId=<groupId> -DartifactId=<artifactId> -Dversion=<version>` for each file is rather tedious. Could create a bat file, but is there a way to do this using maven?

I'm thinking a project for all the jars and a single pom file with all the group ids, artifact ids, versions and filenames and then the possibility of just running `mvn install` in that project, or something along those lines.

Is anything like this possible?

---

***Note:** I'm using Maven 3, but a Maven 2 compatible solution would be nice too.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Recently discovered a new solution to this. Basically you can create a local repository within the project which can be checked in with the rest of the source code. Blogged about it here: http://www.geekality.net/?p=2376.

The gist is to deploy dependencies to a folder in your project.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
    -Durl=file:///dev/project/repo/
    -Dfile=somelib-1.0.jar
    -DgroupId=com.example
    -DartifactId=somelib
    -Dpackaging=jar
    -Dversion=1.0
```

And then simply let Maven know about it and use dependency declarations as normal through your `pom.xml`.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>somelib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Not extremely Maven'y, but it works and moving the dependencies to a company repository later should be quite simple.

Comment: In my case deploy-file had some problems with corporate proxy, but mvn install:install-file with -DlocalRepositoryPath=/dev/project/repo achieved the same result

Answer (score 50):

You can just create pom.xml with multiple executions of [install-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) goal of Maven install plugin. Assuming those files are already available locally somewhere (or you can download them [using Wagon plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/download-mojo.html)).

```
  <project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.somegroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version/>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>install1</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <file>lib/your-artifact-1.0.jar</file>
                <groupId>org.some.group</groupId>
                <artifactId>your-artifact</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                ... other properties
              </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>install2</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
              </goals>
              ... etc

            </execution>
            ... other executions
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>
```

So, with above pom fragment `mvn package` should do the trick.

There are good [Maven POM tutorial](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships.html) and [POM reference](http://maventest.apache.org/pom.html).

Comment: Say you have the pom.xml and a folder called lib where all the jar files are. Could you create an example?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete newb in this area. What would the rest of the file look like? With the pom.xml being as minimum as possible.

Comment: This pom.xml file only installs one artifact. The question calls for multiple artifacts.

Comment: Obviously, example shows an incomplete pom. I've copied corresponding sections to make it more obvious... BTW, someone, please accept the answer.

Comment: So we do this, but now Maven is looking into a different repository than the local one.  How do we force it to look in the local repo?

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the correct example provided by @eugene-kuleshov:

1. Once you configure the `maven-install-plugin` with the goal `install-file` in your `pom.xml` file with multiple executions, one execution per external jar, you have to use these jars in your `pom.xml` as usual:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.some.group</groupId>
       <artifactId>your-artifact</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   The `maven-install-plugin` only copies your external jars to your local `.m2` maven repository. That's it. It doesn't automatically include these jars as maven dependencies to your project.

   It's a minor point, but sometimes easy to miss.
2. You do not need to include any `<repositories>` in your `pom` as long as you are installing the external jars to the `.m2` repository (which is the default)